# Using SAS to write to external Sharepoint library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sas

I need a routine for loading files (.html) onto a sharepoint library using SAS.  The site is outside the firewall (am unable to use the 'map network drive' method).

The sharepoint library is configured with 'No versioning' etc, and my username / password has administrator privileges..

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are easier ways (tools) to do it than SAS, so I'd just let SAS call some other process - e.g. if your SAS is on Windows, it could call (even generate) a Powershell script.
This http://poshcode.org/2122 seems to be a way.

I've done something similar with SAS calling `curl` to upload files to SAS webDAV server.

If you'd like a pure SAS way - it should be doable using new `PROC HTTP` as a web service call.
Refer to
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003286672.htm for SAS side and probably this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx
for Sharepoint side.
Anyway, PROC HTTP seems interesting for some easier things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use plain old SAS to do this.  If you have the SAS Enterprise BI Server product, there is a component called "SAS Web Parts for Microsoft SharePoint", but that is really an interface between Sharpoint and the BI server (so you can display dashboards or run stored processes).

The "easiest" thing to do is create your html files and then use FTP to copy then to the SharePoint server.  Of course, this requires an FTP server on the other end and you would want to engage the help of the Sharepoint administrator.  I've done something similar myself.  I don't know SharePoint myself but there is a way to set it up so that all content that shows up in a directory is automatically recognised.

There may be other solutions and I'd love to see them as well.

Answer (score -1):

Sharepoint has this wonderful web interface. Basically what you do is open your web browser, works best in IE8+ and navigate to your site URL and open your document library. If you select Items in the Ribbon you can upload a document using their interface. :)

SharePoint already exposes several options, using legacy web service and the new rest services.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx